# add a class on product if its $0 - $10,000 woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

This is my example

```
product 1 = $20
product 2 = $50
product 3 = $150
product 4 = $1000


.price50 = products 1 & 2
.price100 = product 3
.price200+ = product 4
```

I would like to have a class on its li.product

so it would look like `<li class="product price50 ">`

Comment: why are u not using IF ELSE or SWITCH CASE? did u tried anything?

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new to this php thing, I don't even know where to start

Comment: did u checked the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If class based on product amount than you can use simple conditions as:

*Store product amount in `$productPrice`, than use it in simple conditions.*

```
<?php
if($productPrice >= 20 &&  $productPrice <= 50){
  $class = 'price50';
}
elseif($productPrice >= 50 &&  $productPrice <= 100){
  $class = 'price100';   
}
else
  $class = 'price200';   
}
?>

<li class="product <?=$class?> ">
```

Comment: @FrancisAlvinTan: glad to help u friend